# Run a script while HTML5 video plays

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-canvas

When using HTML5 video, is it possible to have a constantly running script while the video is playing (but only when its playing)?

For example:

```
video.onplaying = function(e){
    alert("playing");
}
video.bind("ended", function(){ 
    alert('Video Ended'); 
});
```

These are examples I found and tried to incorporate into my player with little success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When video starts call `setInterval()` to start your background task and give it the repeat frequency.

Do tasks in this function.

When video stops call `clearInterval()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval